# Can a single IOS app connect to multiple Parse.com apps?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am currently developing an IOS application for a business client. They have 7 branches in different locations and I am creating a single IOS app for 7 branches. Every user selects own business at the beginning. I want to create 7 different parse backend apps for all branches. My question is if Parse.com allows single IOS app to reach multipe parse.com backend apps?

Comment: On Parse's end, you can only enter one app ID, so I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

So FYI, this is fact possible in a limited capacity. You can easily make a cloud code endpoint which you can call from the user's device via the REST API. So basically, your App is connected to Parse app A, but calls a cloud code endpoint on Parse app B via the REST API.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/myFunction")!)

request.setValue("App Id", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.setValue("Rest API key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")

var error: NSError?
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var dataSTR = NSString(data: NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = dataSTR?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
     // Done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no - the database is meant to represent the entire set of data for a given app. Using multiple databases as your security solution is dangerous and unnecessary.

If you have a Gym client with 7 branches owned by 7 different people, the correct and secure solution here is to build your own back-end that connects to the Parse.com database and only shows the appropriate data to each client.

For more information, check out this post by a Parse.com admin:
https://www.parse.com/questions/multiple-databases

Comment: ok I get it. how about one web client reaches multiple databases on parse.com?

Comment: Sure, that's completely do-able. Seems like a lot more work though!